# Drag and sort partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am trying to add a drag and drop and sortable functionality in my application. What I am trying to do is adding partial views on button click and then trying to move it. Here is the example of what I am trying to do

```
https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable
```

It is not sorting properly. When i use ul or li instead of div tag, it is adding new partial view and causing some strange behaviour. I am not sure what I am missing. Thanks in advance for your help

```
Partial View:

<div class="action-item" id="@ViewBag.DivActionID" style="background-color:#EBF3F8;  padding:10px;">
        <div>
            <img src="~/Images/Move.png" alt="Move" class="editbtn moveaction" />
        </div>

        <div>
                <p>Currently showing actions for @ViewBag.DivActionID</p>
        </div>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(document).on('click', '.moveaction', function (e) {

            $("#actions").sortable({
                revert: true
            });

            $(this).closest(".action-item").draggable({
                connectToSortable: "#sortable",
                helper: "clone",
                revert: "invalid"
            });

            $("ul, li").disableSelection();
        });

        });
</script>

Controller Code:

public ActionResult CreateNewActions(string actionid)
{
    ViewBag.DivActionID = actionid;
    return PartialView("~/Views/Interp/_AddActions.cshtml");
}

Main View:

<div>
     <div id="actions"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var actionidcounter = 0;

    $("#btn_addactions").on('click', function () {                    
        actionid = "ActionID" + actionidcounter;

        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            data: { 'actionid': actionid },
            url: '/Home/CreateNewActions'
        }).success(function (partialView) {            
            actionidcounter++;                
            $('#actions').append(partialView);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What 'strange' behavior? What are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: It is not draggable sometimes and sorting is sometimes an issue.